# Angular 4 application with Bootstrap card behaviour on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to render a table in a component that displays a bootstrap card.
When I look at it in the mobile view via Chrome Developer Tools, I cannot get the table to be responsive inside the card. I didn@t provide a plunker as it is difficult to test on mobile.

Mobile Medium (Typical iPhone)
[image: Image 1]

Looking at the second image I do "Mobile Small" and you can see the card adjusting to less than the width, and continues to do so if I decrease the size of the view.

[image: Image 2]

I have the "standings" component inside a card:

```
  <div class="card">
      <league-info [league]="league"></league-info>
  </div>
```

and the league-info component looks like this:

```html
<div class="card-header"><h5>Standings</h5></div>
<div class="card-block">
  <button md-raised-button color="primary" (click)="tableShowAll()" *ngIf="showAllResults">{{resultButText}}</button>
  <table class="table table-sm">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Place</th>
        <th>Team Name</th>
        <th>Player Name</th>
        <th>GW Points</th>
        <th>Total Points</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let standing of results.slice(0, resultsTableCnt); let i = index">
        <td>{{i+1}}</td>
        <td>{{standing.entryName}}</td>
        <td>{{standing.playerName}}</td>
        <td>{{standing.eventTotal}}</td>
        <td>{{standing.total}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button md-raised-button color="primary" (click)="tableShowAll()">{{resultButText}}</button>    
</div>
```

Comment: try this:  <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> <div class="card">

Comment: That seemed to work pretty well, all the way down to "small device".

Comment: cool :) good luck